# Not Enough Values to Unpack in Python GUI Application

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a GUI application in Python using `Tkinter`. The application displays weather data for any given location and period of time chosen by the user. There are options for the user to display weather data for one week and one month. I am trying to display that data in a table, but I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Documents\Python\Weather Data Application\WeatherData.py", line 109, in getdata
    for i, high, low, precip, conditions in enumerate(list, start = 1):
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 2)
```

The table is supposed to have 5 columns. I am not sure why I am getting this error, as I have all the items I want to display in the list that I define. The part of the code that my error is occurring in is shown below:

```
#Display Data
    for i in range(0,len(value)):
            #Display data for one day
            maxtemp = tk.Label(text = weather['locations'][place]['values'][i]['maxt'])
            mintemp = tk.Label(text = weather['locations'][place]['values'][i]['mint'])
            precipitation = tk.Label(text = weather['locations'][place]['values'][i]['precip'])
            condition = tk.Label(text = weather['locations'][place]['values'][i]['conditions'])
            if (radiovalue.get() == 2 and len(value) == 7) or radiovalue.get() == 3:
                root.withdraw()
                def goBack():
                  root.deiconify()
                  data.withdraw()    
                #new window
                data = tk.Tk()
                tablelabel = tk.Label(data, text = "Weather Data").grid(row = 0, columnspan = 5)
                cols = ('Date', 'High Temperature', 'Low Temperature', 'Precipitation', 'Conditions')
                weatherBox = ttk.Treeview(data, columns = cols, show = 'headings')
                back = tk.Button(data, text = "Go Back", command = goBack).grid(row = 1) 
                for col in cols:
                    weatherBox.heading(col, text = col)
                weatherBox.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 5)
                list = [weather['locations'][place]['values'][i]['maxt'],weather['locations'][place]['values'][i]['mint'],
                        weather['locations'][place]['values'][i]['precip'],weather['locations'][place]['values'][i]['conditions']]
                for i, high, low, precip, conditions in enumerate(list, start = 1):
                    weatherBox.insert(values = (i, high, low, precip, conditions))
```

Comment: `enumerate()` yields 2-element tuples, consisting of the index and the value - but you're trying to unpack that into five variables.  You need another layer of unpacking to handle the sub-elements of your values: `for i, (high, low, precip, conditions) in enumerate(...`.

Comment: I tried that and when I did I got this: TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable float object

Comment: It is because the `list` (better not use keyword as variable) is just a simple list of float numbers.  Also you should not create the window `data` (an instance of `Tk()`) inside the `for i in range(...)` block.  Better refactor your code.